# Can't uninstall Adobe Reader

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, error-handling, software-uninstall

I'm unable remove this as it was not installed completely but showing it in my applist.
I also tried using purge command
[adobe reader is showing in the list though it wasn't installed successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTR9k.png)

```
$sudo apt-get remove acrordrdc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "acrordrdc", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install acrordrdc"

E: Unable to locate package acrordrdc
```

Comment: There is no package of the name `acrordrdc` if you check https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=acrordrdc&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all so the error is correct. We don't know your release, so I won't explore further, but check it wasn't miss-spelt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Adobe Reader DC is available [as Snap](https://snapcraft.io/acrordrdc), so it should be removed as Snap with

```
snap remove acrordrdc
```